# Allow search engine to crawl usernames

Tags: asp.net, passwords, bots, robots.txt

I have a site where users can enter their profile and password-protect certain details. I would like search engines to crawl the 'unprotected' parts of the profile (which varies from user to user). Similar to how if you enter a user's name in facebook, their Facebook profile comes up in the search results. Do I have to do anything special to ensure that the bot doesn't crawl the password-protected sections, but still crawls the (always-public) username?
I'm not sure if this is even an issue, but I'd like to update my robots.txt to allow for this.

Also, how do I ensure that the usernames are available to the bots (in a safe manner)? Do I have to create a separate directory with a list of names, or is there a better way?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search engines will only index what an anonymous user sees. If you don't already, I would create a listing page to browse the user profiles in which you only show the data you want to. This ensures that a link exists for every `userProfile.aspx?uid=XXXXXX` you have. The search engine spiders will not be able to see any data that is behind a password protected.

I would also add a site map to ensure the search engine spiders get to the listing page. Don't assume that Google will magically find ALL of your pages though typically they do based on links to your content. Submit a site map to Google.

*Edit regarding Site Maps and Search Results*
In order for spiders to crawl search results, I would specify an entry in the site map that points spiders to the search results page that displays all (e.g. search.aspx?param=all).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything. Search bots won't be able to access to your protected pages while they'll access without problems to the public content as long as you don't explicitly disallow it on robots.txt

Comment: Hi. My data (including username) is dynamically loaded from the database from one page (userProfile.aspx?uid=XXXXXX). How would it be able to get the list of usernames on the site?

Comment: If you have links to user profiles on your site, then google will reach them. For instance this site, at the right of this comment there is a link to my profile, so google will find it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The problem with my site is that the links aren't permanent like these ones. They come and go when a user requests a search. Will I have to make a directory of all users, or would that seem like spam to a search engine?

Comment: I can't imagine a site where you have user profiles, but there is no link to profiles anywhere but on a search page. Maybe you have an issue there. You should have links to profiles on your public pages

Comment: Agreed. The spiders will not see any listings that are behind a search request unless you specify a default search result listing in a site map that displays all. For instance, search.aspx?param=all .

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I was having trouble logging in with my Yahoo OpenID. The reason there aren't any links is because users are supposed to know the other user's profile name in order to be viewed. There's no reason for a public listing.